# Numpy apply_along_axis wrong dtype infered

Tags: python, numpy

I have following problem when using NumPy:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
get_label = lambda x: 'SMALL' if x.sum() <= 10 else 'BIG'
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [30, 40]])
print np.apply_along_axis(get_label, 1, arr)
arr = np.array([[30, 40], [1, 2]])
print np.apply_along_axis(get_label, 1, arr)
```

Output:

```
['SMALL' 'BIG']
['BIG' 'SMA'] # String 'SMALL' is stripped!
```

I can see that NumPy in some way infers datatype from first value returned by function. I came up with following workaround - return NumPy array from function with explicitly stated dtype instead of string, and reshape the result:

```
def get_label_2(x):
    if x.sum() <= 10:
        return np.array(['SMALL'], dtype='|S5')
    else:
        return np.array(['BIG'], dtype='|S5')
arr = np.array([[30, 40], [1, 2]])
print np.apply_along_axis(get_label_2, 1, arr).reshape(arr.shape[0])
```

Do you know more elegant solutions for this problem?

Comment: It infers the dtype from a test calculation using the first input.  If that returns 'BIG', the string size is set to 3 char long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1, 2], [30, 40]])
arr2 = np.array([[30, 40], [1, 2]])

print(np.where(arr1.sum(axis=1)<=10,'SMALL','BIG'))
print(np.where(arr2.sum(axis=1)<=10,'SMALL','BIG'))
['SMALL' 'BIG']
['BIG' 'SMALL']
```

In a function:

```
def get_label(x, threshold, axis=1, label1='SMALL', label2='BIG'):
    return np.where(x.sum(axis=axis) <= threshold, label1, label2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply_along_axis` is not an elegant solution; it's convenient, but not fast.  Essentially it does

```
In [277]: get_label = lambda x: 'SMALL' if x.sum() <= 10 else 'BIG'
In [279]: np.array([get_label(row) for row in np.array([[30,40],[1,2]])])
Out[279]: 
array(['BIG', 'SMALL'],
      dtype='<U5')
In [280]: res = np.zeros((2,),dtype='S5')
In [281]: arr = np.array([[30,40],[1,2]])
In [282]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     res[i] = get_label(arr[i,:])
     ...:     
In [283]: res
Out[283]: 
array([b'BIG', b'SMALL'],
      dtype='|S5')
```

except it generalizes the shape and deduces the `res` dtype.

With a simple 'iterate over rows' case like this you could just as well do:

```
In [278]: np.array([get_label(row) for row in np.array([[1,2],[30,40]])])
Out[278]: 
array(['SMALL', 'BIG'],
      dtype='<U5')
In [279]: np.array([get_label(row) for row in np.array([[30,40],[1,2]])])
Out[279]: 
array(['BIG', 'SMALL'],
      dtype='<U5')
```

The elegant solution is to avoid the Python level loops, explicit or hidden, using instead compiled array methods like giving `sum` an axis:

```
In [284]: arr.sum(axis=1)
Out[284]: array([70,  3])
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most elegant solution was to convert the numpy array into a pandas DataFrame and then use the pandas.DataFrame.apply function, which does not perform any unwanted conversions:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
get_label = lambda x: 'SMALL' if x.sum() <= 10 else 'BIG'
arr = np.array([[30, 40], [1, 2]])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr) # convert numpy array to pandas dataframe
arr2 = df.apply(get_label,1).to_numpy() # apply function and convert back to numpy array
print(arr2)
```

Output:

```
['BIG' 'SMALL']
```